# Homotopy equivalent dg modules

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

$\newcommand\modl[1]{#1\text{-mod}}$Let $A:=(A,d_A)$ be a dg algebra. I would like to ask about **isomorphisms** in the homotopy category $H(\modl A)$ of the dg category $\modl A$ of dg modules over $A$.

According to Section 2 of [B. Keller-Deriving dg categories](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1994_4_27_1_63_0), the homotopy category $H(\modl A)$ of $\modl A$ is given by:

- objects: dg modules over $A$
- morphisms: for dg modules $M$, $N$, the space of morphisms in $H(\modl A)$ is $H^0(\hom_A(M,N))$.

i.e. A morphism is represented by $\phi\in \hom_A(M,N)$ of degree $0$ such that $d_N\circ \phi=\phi \circ d_M$ where two such morphisms $\phi, \psi:M\to N$ represent the same morphism in $H(\modl A)$ if there is $h\in \hom_A(M,N)$ such that $\phi-\psi = d_N \circ h+h \circ d_M$.

On the one hand, I have a notion of isomorphism in $H(\modl A)$, which is usually referred as homotopy equivalence:

**Definition 1**

$\phi\in \hom_A(M,N)$ represents an isomorphism in $H(\modl A)$ if there is $\psi\in \hom_A(N,M)$ such that

- $\phi\circ \psi -1_N = d_N \circ h_N+ h_N \circ d_N$
- $\psi\circ \phi -1_M = d_M \circ h_M+ h_M \circ d_M$

for some $h_M\in \hom_A(M,M)$ and $h_N \in \hom_A(N,N)$ of degree $-1$.

On the other hand, since $H(\modl A)$ is a triangulated category, an isomorphism can be characterized by (cf. Cor 1.2.6 of [A. Neeman-Triangulated Categories](https://doi.org/10.1515/9781400837212)).

**Definition 2**

$f:M\to N$ is an isomorphism (in the triangulated category) iff
$$M\xrightarrow{f} N \to 0 \to M[1] \tag{*}\label{star}$$
is a distinguished triangle.

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cone{Cone}$Note that there is a distinguished triangle associated to $f:M\to N$, namely
$M\xrightarrow{f} N \to \Cone(f)\to M[1]$.

Comparing it with \eqref{star}, one can obtain an isomorphism $0\to \Cone(f)$.

Now, since $\Cone(f)$ is isomorphic to $0$, the identity map on $\Cone(f)$ must be null-homotopic. That is, for $d=\begin{bmatrix}-d_M & 0 \\ f & d_N \end{bmatrix}$,
there is an $A$-linear map $H=\begin{bmatrix}h_1 & h_2 \\ h_3 & h_4 \end{bmatrix}$ of degree $-1$ such that
$dH+Hd=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$.

After the computation for $f=\phi$, I got $h_1=-h_M$, $h_2=-\psi$, $h_4=h_N$, and moreover, there is a relation: $$h_N\circ \phi -\phi\circ h_M= h_3 \circ d_M - d_N h_3.$$

This is the relation I could not obtain from Definition 1 and started to suspect that definition 1 is not the correct definition for this situation, so I would like to ask if I got anything missing/wrong or those two definitions are not equivalent in this situation.

Comment: In the second case you obtain an adjoint equivalence. It is somewhat stronger but not really since any two equivalent objects are so through an adjoint equivalence. This is ‘well known’.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Does it mean that Definition 2 is stronger than Definition 1 in general, but in this case they are equivalent? May I ask any reference for this, or maybe about 'adjoint equivalence' you mentioned?

Comment: No, they’re always equivalent.